# Selecting contextual search scope

Tags: 2007, search-scope

I have a question regarding the search scopes on sharepoint 2007.

I want to create a feature that will be activated on a web scope.
If the feature is activated on that site and in all document libraries, etc the contexctual search should be activated instead of standard "all sites".

So how can i do it programmatically? Setting conextual search scope (ex: this list: name of the list) selected?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set the search center url:

```
        using (SPSite site = web.Site)
        {
            using (SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb)
            {
                rootWeb.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"] = "/Search/Pages";
                rootWeb.Update();
            }
        }
```

Next you can remove the all sites search scope from the search dropdown grouping:

```
    public void UpdateSearchScopes(SPWeb web)
    {
        SearchContext context;
        using (SPSite site = web.Site)
        {
            context = SearchContext.GetContext(site);
        }
        Scopes scopes = new Scopes(context);
        ScopeDisplayGroup group = scopes.GetDisplayGroup(new Uri(web.Url), "Search Dropdown");

        try
        {
            Scope all = scopes.GetSharedScope("All Sites");
            if (group.Contains(all) == true)
            {
                group.Remove(all);
            }
        }
        catch { }

        group.Update();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, but I don't want to delete the scopes. I just want to select the contextual search scope as default only if the feature is activated on the site (not site col)